# Media computer / NAS with HDMI

Tags: pc, hard-disk, server, data-storage, nas

**What I am trying to achieve :**

Stream media to my TV using the least possible amount of devices.

**What I currently own :**

- A `Western Digital MyCloud Ex 2 Ultra` NAS, and I am somewhat happy/unhappy with it.
- A `Sony PlayStation 4` with the Plex & Netflix apps.

**The problem**

Right now, streaming on the playstation from the NAS using the Plex apps is not really working. 90% of the time the app will say the server is not powerful enough to stream the selected media.
I noticed it happens when I use subtitles. If I don't it works just fine, until I add subtitles then I can never play the media again (even if I remove the sub).
Streaming works like a charm on all other devices in the home, with and without subs, never had any issue.

This leads me to believe the problem is in the playstation app, and all the settings I've changed never had any influence whatsoever.

I'm still in the legal timeframe to return my NAS with a full refund.

This leaves me with 3 solutions :

1. Add yet another device close to the TV specifically for streaming, leaving me with the PS4, the NAS and that new device (3 total).
2. Replace the NAS with one that has an HDMI slot and a decent OS so that I can use that as a storage AND media PC, effectively allowing me to get rid of the console and have 1 computer to rule them all.
3. Do nothing and cry.

I've went with the 2nd solution, because I'm pretty sure I'm not gonna be able to fix the PS4 Plex app and I really don't want another computer there. So, I know it's not your fault NAS, but you're leaving.

**What I need from you guys** (finally, the question)

I'd like a computer that has the following features :

- Can browse internet for leisure, as well as download and use software like Plex or Netflix.
- Can be used to download, store and and use .torrent files
- It is or looks like a Windows/Mac OS, so I can actually use that computer for something else locally or remotely if necessary. (can easily be ignored if it does the rest well enough) What I mean is I don't want a cheap UI where I am forced and limited by a proprietary OS ; I'd like the freedom to manage my own folders like I would on Windows/Mac, and the ability to manage my .torrent (store them and use them)
- Streaming HD (up to 1080p 60fps) videos. Big + if future proof and can play up to 4K 60fps videos.
- Has decent storage : 12Tb <  x < 20Tb
- Has at least 2 USB slots for kb & mouse
- Has an ethernet slot
- Is < 1.000€

I've read synology is the way to go for NAS, yet I had gone with this one because it was cheaper with better reviews. Now that I have used this WD, i realize it's not like a simple windows computer with "just a lot of storage". The OS is actually a really basic UI accessible via IP and I can only install apps within the WD Store, which is pretty crap, let me tell you.

Since I do not know how other devices will work and if they fit my needs, I do hope you guys can shed some light onto my problem, as my knowledge is lacking here.

Thank you very much for reading this far. I hope you have enough information to answer ; if not, make sure to ask a few questions in the comments.

Comment: Raspberry Pi 3 with external hard drive, configured for Plex and torrenting.  But that's what I do, and you might be looking for something a bit different if I'm reading you question right (if the Plex app isn't working right for your PS4 this isn't the right solution).

Comment: If you still have the WD MyCloud, you might want to try asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) before you give up all hope. I do know that video games are off topic there, but your question is about the hardware, so I would ask in meta or the chat room if this question would be on-topic there first before actually asking on the main site. Either way, we can help you pick out a new device here.

Comment: I still have it I'm just afraid to spam SE too much with my question.
And as the day went by, I've realized I still have enough older parts to make a full computer, that I'll probably just put in a Silverstone case for 90€. Then just add a couple of 8tb ironwolf drives in there.
Thanks for the tips, if I change my mind again I'll definitely go have a chat there !